# Fingerprint sensor detected; never unlocks

Tags: debian, pam, laptop, fingerprint

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 14ARE05 and have installed Debian SID on it. There were multiple compatibility issues out-of-the-box, but I've been able to resolve most of them. The only major one that remains is the fingerprint sensor.

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4d Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
```

The sensor is detected by fprintd and finger seems to get successfully registered. However, during login, the fingerprint never matches. Is there a way to check if sensor is malfunctioning?

Answer (score 0):

`fprintd` has a set of tools that, among other things, let you to check if everything is working before you try the login. I think the description for `fprind-verify` is wrong (it is probably what you want to try), but I'm quoting.

> TEST APPLICATIONS
>
> **fprintd-enroll**
> Will enroll the user's right index finger into the
> database.
>
> **fprintd-list** Will list the user's enrolled fingerprints.
>
> **fprintd-verify** Will enroll the user's right index finger into the
> database.
>
> **fprintd-delete** Will delete user's fingerprint data

From: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/fprintd/fprintd.1.en.html

Comment: fprintd-verify also says Match Unsuccessful. But the same sensor is working perfectly in Windows 10